# Select only one employee from every department

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: My table schema and Data]

I want one employee from every department (EmpDepartment), for example in my table there are:

- 3 employees with EmpDepartment 1
- 2 employees with EmpDepartment 2 and
- 1 Employee with EmpDepartment 3

I want EmployeeId, EmployeeName and EmpDepartment of any one employee from each separate department.

Answer (score 1):

Use a windowing function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
     E.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpDepartment) AS RN
  FROM Employee
) X
WHERE X.RN = 1
```

You can add an order clause the the windowing function if you have a business rule that you want to use in picking the employee

eg

```
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpDepartment order by EmployeeId) AS RN
```

Comment: OVER() and PARTITION BY are new for me, will be using in future.It worked for me with order clause without order clause it gives error "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."

Comment: That makes sense @AhsanNadeem -- SQL server does not support without order by -- which is funny because you can say order by empDepartment which actually means nothing since there is only every one.

Answer (score 0):

This will get a random employee from each department due to ordering by NEWID()...

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeEmail
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpDepartment ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
    FROM   dbo.Employee
) x 
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

You can change the order by clause to something else if you want to.

Comment: what exactly is the advantage of adding the overhead of creating a random number for every row in the table.

Comment: Without it I get this error... "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY." It seems to also work if I order by EmpDepartment. Does it work for you without the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: yes -- in some platforms you don't need the order by -- my issue with NEWID is that it is very slow -- best is a column you have an index on.

Comment: Well, on SQL Server 2014 apparently you need the ORDER BY.

Comment: I've become spoiled by DB2

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Top(1) EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EMPDeptartment  FROM Employee WHERE EmpDetpartment = 1

UNION

SELECT Top(1) EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EMPDeptartment  FROM Employee WHERE EmpDetpartment = 2

UNION

SELECT Top(1) EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EMPDeptartment  FROM Employee WHERE EmpDetpartment = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the employee from each department having the minimum `EmployeeID` in that department (since it is not important which employee will be in the results):

```
SELECT e.* FROM Employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Employee 
  WHERE EmpDepartment = e.EmpDepartment AND EmployeeID < e.EmployeeID
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use rownumber to find any employee of a particular dept change rn to any value as 1,2,...etc

```
Select department, employee
from (
   Select department, employee, 
      row_number() over (partition by department order by employee) rn
) 
where rn =1;
```

or use simple group by

```
Select department, max(employee)
from table 
group by department
```

Comment: Your suggestion that `where rn = 2;` makes sense is curious. The OP has stated that department `3` has one employee, hence checking for `rn` values other than `1` won't return an employee for that department.

Comment: That was generic I stated as Op din mention which employee to select as per the data that was generic i meant and i repeat